# MySQLi use query as variable for Find Distance by using Longitude/Latitude

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to find the distance between two points, **BUT** each **latitude** and **longitude** I took from database with based on **POSTCODE**.

I was trying to make query as variable, but I do not know how to make this idea finally work.

Task: I have 10 shops with address and postcode each, and then I have 1000 users addresses with postcodes and I need to find 3 closest shops for each user and ideally extract as spreadsheet, so that for each user will be an extra 3 columns where will be 3 closes shops.

I download full database of postcodes and try to connect users/shops postcodes with postcode database and get latitude and longitude  for each user/shop, but from here I'm now sure what I need to do and how to process it further.

**P.S.** Please do not advertise google map API, I know about it, but it is too expensive for me.

Any suggestions or any help with this task which will move some how further, will be very appreciated.

Thank you.

This is my `PHP` code:

```
$sqlTescLat = "SELECT lat FROM postcodelatlng, tesco WHERE tesco.postcode = postcodelatlng.postcode";
$sqlTescLng = "SELECT lng FROM postcodelatlng, tesco WHERE tesco.postcode = postcodelatlng.postcode";

$sqlShopLat = "SELECT lat FROM postcodelatlng, shops WHERE shops.postcode = postcodelatlng.postcode";
$sqlShopLng = "SELECT lng FROM postcodelatlng, shops WHERE shops.postcode = postcodelatlng.postcode";

$tescoLat = mysqli_query($con,$sqlTescLat);
$tescoLng = mysqli_query($con,$sqlTescLng);
$shopsLat = mysqli_query($con,$sqlShopLat);
$shopsLng = mysqli_query($con,$sqlShopLng);

function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);

    if ($unit == "K") {
        return ($miles * 1.609344);
    } else if ($unit == "N") {
        return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
    }
}

echo distance($tescoLat, $tescoLng, $shopsLat, $shopsLng, "M") . " Miles<br>";
```

This is how database looks like:

```
shops
ID  NAME    ADDRESS             POSTCODE
1   Home1   63 Simmonds Close   BH15 3EB


tesco
ID  NAME            ADDRESS                             POSTCODE
1   Tesco Poole     Waterloo Rd, Poole BH17 7EJ, UK     BH17 7EJ


postcodelatlng(this is big post codes database) as e.g.:
ID  POSTCODE    lat                     lng
1   AB10 1XG    57.144165160000000      -2.114847768000000
```

Updates:

```
$sqlDestLat = "SELECT lat FROM postcodelatlng, tesco WHERE tesco.postcode = postcodelatlng.postcode";
$sqlDestLng = "SELECT lng FROM postcodelatlng, tesco WHERE tesco.postcode = postcodelatlng.postcode";
$sqlOrigLat = "SELECT lat FROM postcodelatlng, shops WHERE shops.postcode = postcodelatlng.postcode";
$sqlOrigLng = "SELECT lng FROM postcodelatlng, shops WHERE shops.postcode = postcodelatlng.postcode";


$sqlDISTANCE="SELECT *, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(('$sqlOrigLat' - abs('$sqlDestLat')) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS('$sqlOrigLat' * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs('$sqlDestLat') *  pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(('$sqlOrigLng' – '$sqlDestLng') * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance FROM tesco, shops, postcodelatlng having distance < 20 BY distance limit 10;"
```

Comment: You have to modify your database table for this kinds of complex searching. Here is an example for `Geo Distance Searching by Latitude and Longitude`. https://www.scribd.com/presentation/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

Comment: What exactly do you mean " I'm now sure what I need to do and how to process it further"? You do have a php code that calculates distances between two sets of coordinates. The code can be optimised (e.g. have a single query and even calculate the distance in mysql), but I do not see any obvious fault in your existing code that would prevent it from working.

Comment: @Shadow it does not work and I have not a clue why, this is the problem. I have tried to make it one line, have a look if you have any suggestions, but it is still does not work.

Comment: Does not work is not really a sufficient error description. You must provide more details (e.g. you need to debug your code).